# В-последних(,) я бы хотел сказать, что дружба — суперважно

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая? Там нет *во-первых* и *во-вторых*, а *в-последних* имеет значение *подводя итог*.

> В-последних(,) я бы хотел сказать, что дружба — суперважно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:

***В-последних,** я бы хотел сказать, что дружба — суперважно.*

**Пояснение**

**Семантика** в конкретном тексте может пониматься по-разному, но **синтаксическая функция** для этого вводного слова не меняется: способ **оформления** текста, порядок **следования** рассуждений.

Орфографический словарь: **в-последних**, вводн. сл.

**Из Нацкорпуса**

**1. Вводное слово** (запятая и тире; вероятно, современное тире)

В. В. Каменский. Землянка (1910)

Росс от безделья лизал свои толстые лапы и посматривал на нас. А Пич вполголоса, но с азартом рассказывал нам какую-то замечательную историю из своей жизни. И по тому, как он мигал глазами, и по тому, как он мечтательно держал набок свою голову, мы решили, что он сам выдумал эту историю и заврался без всякого стеснения. **Но ведь, во-первых, — была мокрая погода, а в-последних, — Пич действительно мог похвастаться молодостью — и это ему простительно.** Мы слушали его сколько могли. Потом наступила наша очередь.

2. **Однако значение наречия тоже возможно**

Андрей Белый. На рубеже двух столетий (1929)

*Так с ужасом воспринимал я «второго математика»; «второй математик» — техническое выражение у нас в доме; и принадлежало оно матери; «первый математик» — папа: и это не «математик»: «математик» он — где-то там, в ужасном месте; у нас в квартире он — Николай Васильевич и — папа; **а «второй математик» — это уже математик во-первых, во-вторых, в-третьих и в-последних: только математик;** и я переживал ужас...*

Comment: Если тире обозначает паузу после вводного слова, то оно заменяет запятую. Следовательно, правильно: _Но ведь, во-первых — была мокрая погода, а, в-последних — Пич действительно мог похвастаться молодостью — и это ему простительно_. И _в-последних_ нужно отделить от союза, т. к. можно переставить или убрать без потери СТРУКТУРЫ.

Comment: Это 1910 год.  Правил Розенталя еще нет, Какие подстановки-перестановки! Перед И лучше запятую поставить. А то два тире там ни к чему.

Comment: Поэтому то есть так знаки стоят? Потому что правил таких ещë не было?

Comment: Да, как я думаю. Единый знак там не нужен. А может, и нужен. Если пауза подчеркивается. Авторская пунктуация.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: @Максим  Кстати, Максим, про вставку у меня не хотите ответить?  А то вряд ли кто будет отвечать, а мне интересно.

Comment: Я точно уверен, что смещающая интонация в этом примере не влияют на запятую, она не нужна. А доказать вам это не очень просто, да и переубедить вас может быть сложно.

Comment: @Максим  А вы слышите, что смещена? Или нет?  И еще вопрос: Лео нечаянно придумал новый синтаксис / или такое встречается регулярно?

Comment: Может, и слышу, но я ставлю знаки в соответствии с правилами, а не интонацией. А какой синтаксис он придумал?

Comment: Зачем разделил сказуемое? Кто-нибудь еще делил?  Может, это тот вариант, для которого правило не подходит, поэтому надо решать по интонационному ПРИНЦИПУ пунктуации.

Comment: Отчего дружба — *важно*, а не *важна*? Правильно было бы: *дружба — это важно*.